# How do I connect to a web app running on an image on docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am learning docker, just getting my feet wet... I begin begging your pardon since I will probably using terminology badly :-(

I have successfully built my first container and run it locally.
The container image is a `node.js` + `express` web app.
Locally I run my image this way:

```
docker run -p 80:3000 myname/myimage
```

If I point my browser to the local server IP

```
http://192.168.1.123:80/
```

I access my app in all of its glory.

Then, I push it to docker hub with this command:

```
docker push myname/myimage
```

So far so good. The question is: am I supposed to be able to run my app from docker cloud, already, or should I push it to AWS, for example?

Comment: [Tryph](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2696355/tryph)'s answer is correct - to add to it, Docker Hub is a public registry, which is a centralised store for Docker images. It just stores images, to use them you need to `docker pull` the image on the host, which downloads it to Docker's local image cache and then you can `docker run` it (also, if you `docker run` an image which you don't have, Docker will look for it on the Hub and download it),

Comment: @EltonStoneman: Can you point me to an up-to-date tutorial to pull an image to some public host (for example AWS) with a free plan? The tutorials I've found are quite outdated...

Comment: Depends how you're using the provider. New AWS accounts get a free VM for 12 months, and you can just remote into the VM, install Docker, and do `docker pull`. It might be easier to use [Docker Cloud](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/getting-started/) though - which gives you a friendly web interface for managing Docker hosts on different clouds. Right now you can use Docker Cloud for free and get a voucher for Digital Ocean which will give you a free VM for a few months. No-one has a "free forever" offer that I know of.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't looking for a free forever offer... Just trying to understand the full logic of docker containers, from the coding to the deploy...

Comment: To better express myself, I'd like to understand a **cli** procedure to commit changes to a docker image, to pull the image to docker hub or docker cloud, and run the image container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By executing `docker push myname/myimage` you only sent your image to docker-hub.
This image can then be run to create a container; but as is, it is not running.

You effectively will have to run it on any machine or service in order to access your app.

concerning the terminology:

- you **build** an **image**, not a container
- you **push** (or **pull**) an **image** to (from) docker-hub
- you **run** a **container** from an image

Comment: Thanks, above all for the terminology suggestions... :-)

Comment: Can you point me to an up-to-date tutorial to pull an image to some public host (for example AWS) with a free plan? The tutorials I've found are quite outdated...